# What framework I need to learn to make an ecommerce web app in java or C++

Tags: java, c++, web-applications, frameworks

I'm learning JAVA and C++ both, and I'm not sure what I framework should I chose to make an ecommerce web app where people can sell their things, take eBay for example. From the childhood I wanted to make a web app where people can sell and buy. And I'm so much confused with all the option available online.

1. Should I chose Spring framework for JAVA to make a webapp like Ebay?
2. What is the best framework for C++ to build an e-commerce webapp?
3. I know about the Ruby on Rails but I don't like the syntax and style of that language, I'm in love with C, C++ and JAVA so please suggest me what frameworks I should learn and also recommend me other things that I'm not aware of.

I did a lot of research but I'm not an expert so I'm asking you guys. Your help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why don't you go for some php framework like opencart. It will provide you free and ready base for eCommerce platform.

Comment: As you are going to start a web-application you should go with Java

Comment: @VimalBera Thanks for the suggestion but I don't know PHP and I think JAVA is the best language for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very new to web apps as well but I am working with [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) and have found it very good. It runs on JavaScript not java but it would not take long to learn if you know java.

Comment: Meteor looks pretty good but I feel comfortable with Java, just thinking about the future JAVA has more scope so.

Comment: @Amession If want to develop for the web you will need to know html and css, JavaScript and Jquery go hand in hand with them for basic web sites. JavaScript is used far more for the web than java which would be used for say a android app.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the most popular open source E-commerce frameworks are
Magento
Spree
Wordpress
Broadleaf
Apache Ofbiz

as you are learning java Apache Ofbiz will suit you best according to me.
Or you can search abt them and find out which suits you best
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_software_e-commerce_web_application_frameworks